# Hibernate one to many retrieval

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables parent and child. I have data in these two tables as parent:

```
PARENT_ID   city
----------------
20           B 
22           C
24           D
```

child:

```
CHILD_ID    PARENT_CHILD_JOIN        phone
------------------------------------------
2             20                     1111
3             20                     2222 
4             22                     3333
```

I have related these two tables in child.hbm.xml as:

```
<many-to-one name="myMtO" class="com.Parent" fetch="select">
        <column name="PARENT_CHILD_JOIN" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

in parent.hbm.xml:

```
<set name="mySet" table="child" cascade="save-update"  inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="PARENT_CHILD_JOIN" not-null="true" />
        </key>
<one-to-many class="com.Child" />  
</set>
```

While saving I am saving only `parent , session.save(parent);`
By doing this PARENT_CHILD_JOIN value in child table is automatically populated from PARENT_ID column from parent table.

Now here I want to fetch data as:

```
select c.phone 
from child c, parent p 
where c.PARENT_CHILD_JOIN = p.PARENT_ID
```

But its saying PARENT_CHILD_JOIN column is not present in child. It is right. Since while saving I have not set it explicitly.

Can anybody tell me how can I retrieve these one to many data ?

Answer (score 2):

this is a problem that SQL has, not really a hibernate problem. There are many ways you can fix it in SQL (e.g. minus statement).
To simulate the same behaviour in Hibernate you can use the IN/NOT IN statements. This is the most simple way i found (Taken into consideration that you have to match "n" child column values, not only one).

To be more specific :
1. select from child table where column values IN (...). Set projection on FK column, or another column you want (i will use the FK column , e.g. the id of the parrent).
2. select from child table where column values NOT IN (...). Set projection on FK, or another column you want (same here : i will use the FK column , e.g. the id of the parrent).
3. select all the parrents , where ID IN query results from point 1, and ID NOT IN query results from point 2.

This way you can also be sure you wont get duplicates of the parrent objects. And if you want pagination, you can also use the last query i described.

Please provide some feedback if that helped.

Hope that helps, Nicolae

Comment: You have two different accounts. Please decide which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

HQL uses entities and their properties. It doesn't use table and column names.

```
select c.phone from Child c inner join c.myMtO
```

Note that this join (and the where clause in your query) doesn't serve any purpose, since all the Child are linked to a parent (the join column being not null).

The Hibernate documentation has a [whole chapter dedicated to HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql). Read it.

Side note: `myMtO` is really a terrible name.

Comment: Thanks JB. But what if I want to use where condtion since I want to add where condition in my query                                     select c.phone from Child c , parent p inner join c.myMtO where p.city = 'B' , since its still returning all results.

Comment: then give an alias to the joined entity: `select c.phone from Child c inner join c.myMtO parent where parent.city = 'B'`. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Thanks again JB for your help!!! From documentation I gone through where clause section and tried some foo examples but didnt succedded.                                                          But now its returning correct result . Thanks !!!!

Comment: Hello @JB Nizet . In above relation I tried to update child table's phone column. I want to update all phone values to '000000' where parent-child join condtion met(where child.PARENT_CHILD_JOIN=20).  I tried like ,                                                Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, 20);
Child c = (Child) p.getMySet().iterator().next();
c.setphone("00000000");
session.save(p);
But its creating duplicate row for some records in child table.How can i go for updating child record.

Comment: Session.save does that: it creates a new entity. You don't have to call any session method to modify an entity. You load it, modify it, and Hibernate saves all the modifications automatically.

Comment: Ok.@JB Nizet. But what about where clause condtion while doing update. in normal DB way I can do , update child set phone='000000' where c.parent_child_join in (select id from parent where parent_id=20) but in hibernate not sure how to do this ?

Comment: You do that in hibernate only when you have to update a whole lot of entities at once. Otherwise, you just load the entity and modify it. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct